Lightning-datatable column value overflowing into the next column
Some items of the Part Name column go beyond its configured column width.
In the snippet provided, the first item is displayed as expected. However, the value of the second item is overflowing into the Quantity column.
Here is the HTML -
<lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={vendorQuoteParts}
       columns={vendorQuotePartsColumns} resize-column-disabled
       hide-checkbox-column="true" suppress-bottom-bar="true"
       max-column-width="190" oncellchange={handlePartsDatatableUpdate}
       onrowaction={handleDeleteAction}>
</lightning-datatable>

And here is how the columns are configured in JS -
@track vendorQuotePartsColumns = [
    { label: 'Part Name', fieldName: 'partName', initialWidth: 190, wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true },
    { label: 'Quantity', fieldName: 'Quantity__c', type: 'number', editable: true, hideDefaultActions: true, cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'columnBackgroundColor' }, alignment: 'center' } },
    { label: 'Unit Price', fieldName: 'Unit_Price__c', type: 'currency', editable: true, hideDefaultActions: true, cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'columnBackgroundColor' }, alignment: 'left' } },
    { label: 'Manufacturer', fieldName: 'Manufacturer__c', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true, cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' } },
    {
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 5,
        typeAttributes: {
            name: 'delete',
            iconName: 'action:delete',
            iconPosition: 'right',
            variant: 'bare',
            alternativeText: 'Delete',
        },
    }
];



I tried replicating your issue and found the issue is with your column attribute defination. wrapText is rootcause.
Change the part name column defination from this
{ label: 'Part Name', fieldName: 'partName', initialWidth: 190, wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true },

to
{ label: 'Part Name', fieldName: 'partName', initialWidth: 190, hideDefaultActions: true },

Check this images from my org:-



I want the wrapText to be true because our part name values are super long. This is a request from the business.

I have tried your code and it is working as expected.
HTML::
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">  
        <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={data}
            columns={columns} resize-column-disabled
            hide-checkbox-column="true" suppress-bottom-bar="true"
            max-column-width="190" oncellchange={handlePartsDatatableUpdate}
            onrowaction={handleDeleteAction}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>

JS::
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import generateData from './generateData';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Part Name', fieldName: 'partName', initialWidth: 190, wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true },
    { label: 'Quantity', fieldName: 'Quantity__c', type: 'number', editable: true, hideDefaultActions: true, cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'columnBackgroundColor' }, alignment: 'center' } },
    { label: 'Unit Price', fieldName: 'Unit_Price__c', type: 'currency', editable: true, hideDefaultActions: true, cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'columnBackgroundColor' }, alignment: 'left' } },
    { label: 'Manufacturer', fieldName: 'Manufacturer__c', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true, cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' } },
    {
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 5,
        typeAttributes: {
            name: 'delete',
            iconName: 'action:delete',
            iconPosition: 'right',
            variant: 'bare',
            alternativeText: 'Delete',
        },
    }
];

export default class BasicDatatable extends LightningElement {
    data = [];
    columns = columns;

    connectedCallback() {
        const data = generateData({ amountOfRecords: 10 });
        this.data = data;
    }
}

generateData.JS::
export default function generateData({ amountOfRecords }) {
    return [...Array(amountOfRecords)].map((_, index) => {
        return {
            partName: `Name Test, Test,Test,tesetet,testsTest, Test,Test,test(${index})`,
            Quantity__c: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
            Unit_Price__c: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            Manufacturer__c: 'PRIDE MOBILITY',            
        };
    });
}

OUTPUT::


Tushar Jadav - I still have issues with data overflowing into the other column

@Sumesh, If possible please share the full code so we can reproduce the issue and check.
